# Proof of the Darboux's Theorem with lemma.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Darboux's Theorem as specified in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Let $g(x)=f(x)-dx$ on $[a.b]$

Then $g'(x)=f'(x)-d$

Then by hypothesis, we can say $g'(a)<0<g'(b)$ and it is enough to show that $g'(c)=0$ for some $c$ in $(a.b)$

I first proved that if $g$ is differentiable on $[a.b]$ and satisfies $g'(a) <0< g'(b)$, then there exists a point $x$ in $(a.b)$ such that $g(a)>g(x)$ and point $y \in (a.b)$ such that $g(y)< g(b).$

In fact, I am not sure how above proof will lead to $g`(c)=0$ for some $c$ in $(a.b)$

Can anyone explain?

Comment: $g(x) = f(x) - dx$ does not imply $g(x) = f(x) - d.$

Comment: sorry should ve been derivative

Comment: Was there a theorem in a slightly earlier part of the course whose conclusion was that there must be a point with a zero derivative?  You can look up the original in *Démonstration d'une Méthode pour resoudre les Egalitez de tous les degrez* (1691), although your calculus book most certainly states it (usually with a proof that depends on continuous functions having max and min, a statement they are often reluctant to prove).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $f$ is defined in a compact $[a,b]$, then by Weierstrass' Theorem $f$ attains to a minimum for some point $c$ in $[a,b]$.

Now, as $f'(a) < 0$, there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x) < f(a)$, thus $a < c$. Similarly show that $c < b$.

Next, use that $f'_-(c) \leq 0$, $f'_+(c) \geq 0$. As $f'(c) = f'_+(c) = f'_- (c)$ then $f'(c) = 0$.